# Javascript canvas fill intersecting shapes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have these functions to draw regular polygons or any shape defined by an array of points.

```
function polygon(ctx, x, y, radius, sides, startAngle, anticlockwise) {
    if (sides < 3) return;
    var a = (Math.PI * 2)/sides;
    a = anticlockwise?-a:a;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.rotate(startAngle);
    ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
    for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(radius*Math.cos(a*i), radius*Math.sin(a*i));
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}

function plotpolygon(radius, sides, color) {
    var context = document.getElementById("logo-canvas").getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    polygon(context, 256, 256, radius, sides, -Math.PI/2);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}

function plotshape(xpoints, ypoints, color) {
    var context = document.getElementById("logo-canvas").getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath;
    context.moveTo(xpoints[0], ypoints[0]);
    for (var i=1; i < xpoints.length; i++) {
            context.lineTo(xpoints[i], ypoints[i]);
    }
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}
```

The polygons and shapes are fine, the problem is the fill color.
If I call in the following order:

```
plotpolygon(94, 3, 'yellow');
plotshape(xpoints, ypoints, 'brown');
```

The result should be yellow triangle with brown shape partially overlapping it.
However, I get the place where shapes overlap - yellow, places where not overlapped - brown.
I have tried composition as suggested by [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) but it didn't help.

What's is more strange to me is that I have more polygons on the canvas, putting them always on top - most of them are overlapped, but they have their own colors fine. It is when I add a shape the problem starts to occur..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo that causes the first triangle drawing styles to be continued in the plotshape.

Fix: the beginPath inside plotshape must have parentheses:

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

Slightly refactored Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/adHdr/

Comment: You probably mean `beginPath()` rather than `beginShape()` unless I miss some new method ?

Comment: I swear I was looking at the code for two days, trying all the possibilities.. Thank you

Comment: @Ken Yes, a typo! I guess I should have reversed my processing order (1) type (2) think  ==> (2) then (1)!